# kosher food ideas without refrigeration

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, travel

What kosher food should I pack for a one-week trip?  I won't have access to a fridge; and no kosher food will be available at my destination.

The only food idea I can think of is tuna.  That would get very boring.  I need more variety.

Comment: Where are you going, and (optionally) why? How are you getting there? (Optionally:) Where will you be staying: a tent? a backpackers' hostel? a hotel? a private home? (See also ["Being a houseguest in a non-frum or non-Jewish home"](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16022/being-a-houseguest-in-a-non-frum-or-non-jewish-home).) Will you have access to a fridge there? Can you buy kosher cheese there? Kosher meat? Kosher bagels?

Comment: No kosher food available... no fridge

Comment: Your reply was rather mediocre. If you want better answers, try to answer at least three or four of the above questions.

Comment: It would also be best to provide the information in the question for context, rather than _actually_ answering @unforgettable's question.

Comment: I agree with @SethJ. Especially, [edit] into the question how long you'll be traveling for. A five-hour road trip is quite different from a five-month stay, in terms both of how much variety is needed and of what things are to be considered perishable.

Comment: I'm staying 1 week

Comment: [La Briute](http://www.labriutemeals.com/) Makes kosher microwave meals. They come double-wrapped, so you can make them in a non-kosher microwave. They're mediocre, but better than eating just tuna for a week.

Comment: @Daniel: The answer already mentions LaBriute meals; it would be better if you'd edit your comment into the answer. :)

Comment: Dear OP: I think the reason why you got so few upvotes is because your question is missing so much detail. Oh well. Anyway: How was your trip? What did you eat?

Comment: The trip was awsome!  Thanks for asking.  As it turns out I was able to organize a mini-fridge big enough to bring a bunch of prepared food from the kosher market, but I will definitely refer to these great answers for future trips where I may not be so fortunate.

Comment: Good that it worked out! In that situation, if you can cook/boil the food you take, think how it's mostly animal products that really need refrigeration. So you can get the same kind of complete protein by making sure to eat both grains and legumes during the day, e.g. rice + lentils, barley + beans... which are all dried or even canned. Plus vegetables, fruit, nuts, and seeds should give you basically the right nutrition around that. There are lots of vegetables that can keep for a week outside the fridge. And if it's only that long, you'd be fine on that diet even without thinking about it.

Answer (score 4):

(If you want hot food, then instead see the second half of [the linked post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26073/1215). Some things listed there are easy, like instant soup-in-a-cup.)

If you're fine with cold food, then here are some ideas:

Bread: Pita bread or matzah are dense and compact. Another possibility: take along a bread machine - you can buy flour, yeast, etc., anywhere. ([Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/37/alex) has done this on a trip with his family.)

Fish: Canned tuna or salmon. Vacuum-packed tuna without the water. Canned herring in paprika sauce. (Delicious. Try it.) Canned sardines in mustard sauce (but the room and your breath will smell very bad). Canned herring in mustard sauce. Canned "tuna salad" in onions and tomato sauce. Fully cooked and ready to eat (or ready to heat) vacuum-packed salmon or tuna fillets.

Miscellaneous: Vegemite. (Spread an extremely thin layer on bread.) Canned baked beans. Peanut butter. (You can get by for a while eating nothing but peanut butter. When you're hungry, spoon some into a bowl and "enjoy".) Kraft cinnamon-raisin-granola peanut butter. Jam. Chocolate spread. Nutella!

Cereal: Your favorite kind. Granola travels well: it's very dense. Add milk or water. Also add some juicy raisins or other dried fruit if you want.

Milk: Powdered, evaporated, or condensed milk. Or aseptic-packed milk (like Parmalat, which has a hechsher in the US). Or aseptic-packed soy milk, almond milk, or flax milk. Try one of these milks at home; see if you like it. Even if you don't like it plain, you might tolerate it in cereal. After leaving soy milk unrefrigerated, unforgettableid has found that it doesn't go sour for some time: maybe a couple of days or more. Sniff carefully. If it's cool but above freezing, storing it just outside a window might work.

Water: Bring a big water bottle. Make sure that the manufacturer claims it's freezer-safe. Fill it up halfway with water, then freeze it the night before you travel.

Vegetables: Enjoy as many salads as you want.  Though lettuce goes bad soon, bell peppers and other veggies are great.

Fruit: Most fruits aside from berries will last you a week.  This includes avocados, which are great for long trips.

Oils, vinegars, spice, etc: Lots of shelf-stable foods.

Snacks: Unsalted pretzels. Granola bars. Chips and (individually packaged) salsa. Single-serve packages of apple sauce.

If you bring nuts or chips, repack them into single-serving plastic sandwich bags before you travel. These foods are very calorie-dense. If you eat them straight out of the original package, it can take immense self-control not to eat 500 Calories' worth in one sitting.

Meals: Shelf-stable, self-heating, packaged meals such as [LaBriute](http://labriutemeals.com/main.htm) brand.

Have a good trip!

<sub>This post is community wiki. Please edit it, add ideas, and remove mediocre ideas.</sub>

Comment: @Alex, the asker assumed no kosher flour is available.

Comment: @msh210: okay, I assumed he/she meant that no specifically kosher brands are available. [FWIW, I found flour with a hechsher even in some quite remote places in northern Canada - once, if I recall correctly, in the grocery store at a native (First Nations) town.]

Comment: @msh210: is the asker really excluding things that don't need a hechsher? If so, he should ask "there will be no food available at my destination"

Comment: @Menachem, I don't know. This answer does suggest bringing along water.

Comment: @msh210: I assumed that the asker will have access to water. The reason why I suggested bringing bottled ice was for convenience: it stays very cold for hours (even colder than "cold" tap water). It's good on long drives: you can sip cold water without having to stop to obtain it.