# Pesach cleaning at non religious house

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven, home-house, cleaning, hachnasat-orchim-guests

If I'm boarding at a non religious persons house (they don't keep kosher), what are the rules for cleaning for pesach? I share the pantry and fridge so I don't know what to clean and how well to clean it.

Comment: Related / more general: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40778 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26072 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16022

Comment: Because of the difficulties involved, a theoretical discussion would not really help. If possible, you should find a rabbi in your area who has helped people in similar situations. Sometimes they can also arrange for you to stay somewhere kosher for Pesach.

Comment: I VTC'd. This really looks like a psak question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic operating principles: make sure your food is not contaminated by chametz, and make sure you don't own any chametz.

As far as what you eat, you'd need to clean your spaces well enough that chametz doesn't wind up in your food. If there are crumbs in the fridge/pantry that could get into your Passover food, clean them -- or keep your Passover food in sealed bags. (If you need to kasher a kitchen or the like, that's a different discussion.)

As for ownership, either you get rid of all the chametz you own; or seal it off someplace and sell it to a non-Jew. (E.g. put all your chametz in a taped box in the back of the fridge.)

That's the basic theory.

(Yes if you want to complicate things, there's the Vilna Gaon's opinion that you shouldn't even have another Jew's chametz in your house ... assuming a boarding situation is considered "your house" ... but that's a separate discussion.)